# Julia Flux withgradient operation

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am a newbie to Julia and Flux with some experience in Tensorflow Keras and python. I tried to use the `Flux.withgradient` command to write a user-defined training function with more flexibility. Here is the training part of my code:

```
    loss, grad = Flux.withgradient(modelDQN.evalParameters) do
        qEval = modelDQN.evalModel(evalInput)
        Flux.mse(qEval, qTarget)
    end
    Flux.update!(modelDQN.optimizer, modelDQN.evalParameters, grad)
```

This code works just fine. But if I put the command `qEval = modelDQN.evalModel(evalInput)` outside the `do end` loop, as follows:

```
    qEval = modelDQN.evalModel(evalInput)
    loss, grad = Flux.withgradient(modelDQN.evalParameters) do
        Flux.mse(qEval, qTarget)
    end
    Flux.update!(modelDQN.optimizer, modelDQN.evalParameters, grad)
```

The model parameters will not be updated. As far as I know, the `do end` loop works as an anonymous function that takes 0 arguments. Then why do we need the command `qEval = modelDQN.evalModel(evalInput)` inside the loop to get the model updated?

Comment: Should the `qEval` update continuously?

Comment: @Shayan This is just one update on a mini-batch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that anything to be differentiated has to happen inside the (anonymous) function which you pass to `gradient` (or `withgradient`), because this is very much not a standard function call -- Zygote (Flux's auto-differentiation library) traces its execution to compute the derivative, and can't transform what it can't see.

Longer, this is Zygote's "implicit" mode, which relies on global references to arrays. The simplest use is something like this:

```
julia> using Zygote

julia> x = [2.0, 3.0];

julia> g = gradient(() -> sum(x .^ 2), Params([x]))
Grads(...)

julia> g[x]  # lookup by objectid(x)
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 4.0
 6.0
```

If you move some of that calculation outside, then you make a new array `y` with a new `objectid`. Julia has no memory of where this came from, it is completely unrelated to `x`. They are ordinary arrays, not a special tracked type.

So if you refer to `y` in the gradient, Zygote cannot infer how this depends on `x`:

```
julia> y = x .^ 2  # calculate this outside of gradient
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 4.0
 9.0

julia> g2 = gradient(() -> sum(y), Params([x]))
Grads(...)

julia> g2[x] === nothing  # represents zero
true
```

Zygote doesn't have to be used in this way. It also has an "explicit" mode which does not rely on global references. This is perhaps less confusing:

```
julia> gradient(x1 -> sum(x1 .^ 2), x)  # x1 is a local variable
([4.0, 6.0],)

julia> gradient(x1 -> sum(y), x)  # sum(y) is obviously indep. x1
(nothing,)

julia> gradient((x1, y1) -> sum(y1), x, y)
(nothing, Fill(1.0, 2))
```

Flux is in the process of changing to use this second form. On v0.13.9 or later, something like this ought to work:

```
opt_state = Flux.setup(modelDQN.optimizer, modelDQN)  # do this once

loss, grads = Flux.withgradient(modelDQN.model) do m
        qEval = m(evalInput)  # local variable m
        Flux.mse(qEval, qTarget)
    end

Flux.update!(opt_state, modelDQN.model, grads[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helps a lot. I checked the official docs for the `setup` command and it returns 404. What is the second argument that it takes? Is it a `Params` type?

Comment: Docs are in progress.. but no, it's the model itself. Params belongs to the "implicit" mode.